# WPF WebView shows no content

Tags: c#, wpf, webview, wpf-controls

Simply put, the new Edge powered WebView control isn't showing anything when I attempt to browse.

I've tried it with an 'out-of-the-box' WPF app and still showing nothing when browsing to https://www.microsoft.com. Anyone come across this before and have any tips?

For the sake of showing the code though - here it is below:

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        wvc.Navigate(new Uri("https://www.microsoft.com"));
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="WebViewTest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:WPF="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Toolkit.Win32.UI.Controls.WPF;assembly=Microsoft.Toolkit.Win32.UI.Controls"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WebViewTest"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    Title="MainWindow"
    Width="800"
    Height="450"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
<Grid>
    <WPF:WebView x:Name="wvc" Width="200" Height="400" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: Why did not you use `WebBrowser`?

Comment: was having trouble rendering items correctly or even using things like sockets. I assume it's because WebBrowser uses IE7 under the hood